# Boost.Asio wrong local endpoint

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

code example:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_service  service;
    auto sock_ = new boost::asio::basic_stream_socket< boost::asio::ip::tcp >(service);
    if(sock_){
        try {
            boost::asio::ip::address_v4 ipa = boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(argv[1]);
            boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<  boost::asio::ip::tcp > address(ipa, (unsigned short) atoi(argv[2]));
            sock_->connect(address);
            std::cout<<"connected. local address:"<<sock_->local_endpoint()<<" remote address:"<<sock_->remote_endpoint()<<std::endl;
        } catch (const boost::system::system_error& e)
        {
            std::cout<<"ERROR:"<<e.what();
        }
    }
    int dummy;
    std::cin>>dummy;
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 computers.

1. output from computer A:connected. local address:XXXXXX remote
   address:YYYYY (where XXXXX and YYYY real IPs(IPs same to ping output))
2. output from computer B:connected. local address:**127.0.0.1** remote
   address:YYYYY (where YYYY real IP(IPs same to ping output))

Computer A and B have only 1 NIC
Why I got 127.0.0.1? I cant make real connection from IP 127.0.0.1 to YYYY. 
how to fix it?
**update:**
 even windows sockets return 127.0.0.1 on problematic host, see code below

```
WSADATA wsaData;
auto iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    return 1;
}
SOCKET ConnectSocket;
ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {

    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
sockaddr_in clientService;
clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;

clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
clientService.sin_port = htons((unsigned short) atoi(argv[2]));
iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & clientService, sizeof (clientService));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
struct sockaddr_in sin;
int addrlen = sizeof(sin);
if(getsockname(ConnectSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &addrlen) == 0 &&
   sin.sin_family == AF_INET &&
   addrlen == sizeof(sin))
{
    char *ip = inet_ntoa(sin.sin_addr);
    std::cout<<ip<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

127.0.0.1 was routed via real NIC  :) connection succeeded from 127.0.0.1 to remote ip because of routing :'(

Comment: Aw. That's pretty bad. I should have mentioned it (how did you achieve the routing? Perhaps it'll help people diagnose the issue if they have the same thing)

Comment: "how did you achieve the routing? " I still investigating it :))

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing APIs, compiler glitches and making the wrong assumptions. Here's the code *greatly* simplified:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf6c0d2b201e3b41)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    namespace ba = boost::asio;
    using ba::ip::tcp;

    ba::io_service service;
    tcp::socket s(service); 

    if (argc<3)
        return 255;

    try {
        auto it = tcp::resolver(service).resolve({argv[1], argv[2]});
        s.connect(*it); // first resolved value

        std::cout << "Connected " << s.local_endpoint() << " -> " << s.remote_endpoint() << "\n";

        // demo write
        ba::write(s, ba::buffer("hello world\n"));
    } catch (const boost::system::system_error& e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR:" << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

On the online demo, the output is:

```
Connected 127.0.0.1:40468 -> 127.0.0.1:6767
hello world
```

Indeed, when I connect to a remote host not on the loopback network, I get:

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ ./test serverbox 6767
Connected 192.168.188.20:47338 -> 192.168.188.24:6767
```

I'm not too sure hwy you'd get the loopback address there, but I wouldn't at all rule out the possibility that you're doing the `tostring` wrong.

See

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address/to_string.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_endpoint/operator_lt__lt_.html

Comment: Hi, thank you for responce!  tested you code, output is:  Connected 127.0.0.1:54182 -> 172.16.31.7:7900 current hosthost IP is : 172.20.10.137, remote ip is: 172.16.31.7. same problem

Comment: Doing some research my guess is you run on WinXP/2003 server or older? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9b280699-fa48-4461-8875-bb446b6ea48a/why-cant-we-connect-to-loopback-address-from-non-loopback-addresses-anymore?forum=wfp

Comment: windows 7 professional French, do you think is it OS problem? I disabled firewall/antivirus same result.